# Opening TileMill from Ubuntu launcher after building from source

Tags: ubuntu, tilemill

I build TileMill from source following this [tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/source/). Now I can open it by going to the folder `cd ~/tilemill` and run `node index.js`. This all works fine. But I want to open it using the Ubuntu launcher. What do I have to change to do that?

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 and use TileMill Version 0.10.1

Comment: Just out of curiosity (as an Ubuntu user), why are you building Tilemill from source?

Comment: There were some problems with an other mapnik installation.

Comment: @mapBaker To get the latest functions from the dev version

Comment: @bennos well I know there is an IP address you can run in your browser, which is how I see people using the Dev versions of Mapbox stuff...(tilemill, mapbox studio). Otherwise... dev is dev!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this topic is more about Ubuntu and creating a launcher, than about GIS.

You can find a detailed explanation about creating a launcher at the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles). The main part is a .desktop file you can create anywhere (for example your Desktop), which you can add to the Ubuntu launcher. An example for the file would be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.10
Name=TileMill
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/path/to/tilemill/index.js
Icon=/home/path/to/tilemill/tilemill.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

After creating and saving that file, make it executable in the terminal or right click the icon - go to Permissions tab - and check the "Allow executing the file as program".

To get it also to Unity Launcher copy/move the file to `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`

Worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 and I guess it will work also on 13.10